# Why isn't JQuery changing CSS class?

Tags: jquery, css, flask, bootstrap-4

Does anyone know why the following JQuery isn't working properly? When I click a link in the navbar I want it to change style (background and font color):

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("ul li a").click(function(){
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I'm confident that the CSS is correct because when I hardcode class="active" into the HTML it takes on the correct style. However, currently when I click on any link in the navbar all of the links in the navbar flash in and out of the style that I want the link that I just have clicked on to change to. Hopefully that makes sense. Currently the result looks similar to the CSS :active selector but when I click on 1 link in the navbar all of the links flash.

Here are the HTML elements:

```
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/repository">Repository</a></li>
            <li><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="/bio">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

In case it makes a difference, I am also using Flask and Bootstrap for this site.
Any help would be appreciated. If all goes well this will be my first website.

Comment: What does the HTML (including `href`) for the links look like? When you were hardcoding the `class="active"` in your test, what element were you adding it to?

Comment: Have just edited them into my post.

Comment: And the other question? Let's not be **too** cryptic like your namesake? ;-)

Comment: Does the page refresh? Cause if so, your Javascript will refresh too. If you don't cancel the default action of the anchor tag, in this case, go to this page, and it's non Ajax, so the server will than refresh to thta page, thus cancelling all your actions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm trying to add `class="active"` to the relevant item of the list. E.g. `<li><a href="/" class="name">Home</a></li>` Not confident that I understand your question, but hopefully that is the answer you need. I'm looking to add class to the <a>. Hah not intentional. I have been considering changing to Zathras.

ah totally unintended. Perhaps

Comment: @AmbassadorKosh - By `class="name"` there did you mean `class="active"`? If so, it clears my question. (Great show BTW. Really loved it. Doesn't re-watch as well as I would have liked, but fantastic the firs time.)

Comment: @Dorvalla Sorry I am not sure. Though I do know it sends a new "GET" request for everytime I click on a link, so perhaps that is the cause? E.g.
`127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2020 17:21:10] "GET /events HTTP/1.1" 200 -` In the terminal I can't see any evidence of the page refreshing.

Comment: Yes `class="active" ` 
I am happy to meet a fellow fan :) we seem to be few and far between. I only watched for the first time this year. I think we could have done without the movies.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("li").find("a").on("click",function(){
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });
        });
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Thanks for commenting though.

Answer (score 0):

You've said the links look like this:

```html
<ul class="navvy" id="responsive-navvy"><li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

and you've said that you want to follow the link.

Following that kind of link will trigger a request to the server, and then when the response is received, the browser will tear down the DOM of the page (including any changes to `class` you've made) and replace it with the result of parsing the HTML of the new page.

You either need to either:

- Not follow the link, or
- Add the class on page load to match the path of the loaded page

Looking at the first one: If you don't follow the link, then of course there's no request to the server and you don't get the response; you have to update the page in a different way. You can use [`replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) or [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) to update the URL without changing the page content, and then change the page content separately with DOM manipulation.

Looking at the second: If you want to follow the link and have the server drive the content, you could add some code on page load to highlight the relevant nav link. Something along these lines:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul li a[href=" + location.pathname + "]").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Ok, thank you kindly for your answer. I will try it out after dinner. I'm not going to use replacestate or pushState as they don't seem to have much browser support.

Comment: @AmbassadorKosh - They have near-universal browser support and are in widespread use. Perhaps you were looking at the row about whether `title` is used, which is indeed not well-supported (but also not needed).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I haven't got it working yet, but I am wondering if I have bitten off more than I can chew here as I am still very much a beginner. I really appreciate your help though. I'm tempted to take the easier route, which for me is it hardcode the navbar onto each HTML page.